# How do I connect 2 iCloud accounts to a single iCloud Photo Library

Tags: icloud, photos

I am trying to have all the photos from both my iPhone and my wife's iPhone linked to the same iCloud Photo Library so from both of our devices we can have access to the same Photos without needing the same iCloud account on both devices.

Is this at all possible or is there a workable work around that will get the same functionality?

Comment: as connect do you mean sharing ?

Comment: This is not possible. iCloud Photo Library functions through (as the name implies) iCloud, and is therefore tied to the Apple ID/iCloud login used to create it.

Comment: Why don't you just share a collective album with one another? Both users will be able to upload pictures/videos to the album. In your photos app just click on Shared and the plus icon to create a new album and share it with her. it emulates what your trying to achieve

Comment: I am looking to accomplish the same thing as Jon. The advantage to Jon's setup is that the Photos app on the desktop can automatically download photos from both photostreams to your home computer. This simplifies the organization of photos because now he won't have to connect his wife's phone and manually download the photos. They will just automatically appear on the desktop. Sharing an album requires the user to select photos and click share. Family sharing won't help in this regard either. To my knowledge this is the only setup that allows you to automate passively merging photos from multi

Answer (score 4):

You need to have an iCloud id just for photos - Login on both devices using a (perhaps new) iCloud id which your photos will 'live' in. Turn off mail, contacts, calendars and reminders and notes on both devices for this shared iCloud id. So from now on, to apple's iCloud servers, it appears both iPhones are owned by the same "person".

After this, set up your mail id on your iPhone and your wife's mail on hers so you have access to your individual email accounts (you can also active contacts, calendars and reminders for this account so they appear on your respective iPhones).

Note: You will be sharing the same iCloud photo library, but also the same iCloud Safari passwords and wallet - but if you are sharing with one another all photos taken from your iPhones then this is (perhaps) a moot point...

Comment: This is the best solution. Apple really needs to give the option save everyone's photos to one master album. Not everyone has an insular and dysfunctional family that requires everything be private. Lots of people have normal families that have no problem sharing photos, just like photo albums are shared.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)

You can both then share the same apps, books, music & photos.

Comment: Shared albums are [limited to 5000 photos at any given time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202299).

Comment: Which limits my suggestion in what way? If you have more than 5000 photos, make another album.

Comment: There are also limits to the number of shared albums you can have, and it'd be obnoxious trying to figure out which shared album to put/pull from. Family Sharing also does not automatically share photos, which is something many couples want. You have to manually select the ones you want to share and put them into the shared Family album.

Comment: @FrodeEvensen -  Sure it does. Did you read the link?

Comment: I am sorry @Tetsujin it was a typo. I meant “faces” and not “photos”. Adding a new comment now and will delete the one with error.

Comment: Family Sharing with iCloud Photos does not support neither faces nor locations, and images in family sharing does not not appear in search results, so it is not a good solution.